# How to create a datepicker like this?

Tags: java, android, mono

[image]

Android 2.2 How to create a datepicker like this ?

Comment: please pick your preferred solution below, and tick it - as per request on your most recent question. Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to create your own `CalendarView` by drawing a `GridView` on a dialog  and render all the dates on the that grid.You need to manually handle start date logic. i.e. from which item of the grid to start showing you date.an on that grid you can draw your marker easily.

and [here is](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/) a good example to start on

Answer (score 2):

You can try this link calender picker like as your requirement [screenshot and documentation](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/CalendarPickerAPI) and samplecode of the project [here](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/#svn/trunk/calendarpicker/CalendarPickerDemo) and you can also download this project apk file [here](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/downloads/list)....!

You download this Project full Source code link [here](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/downloads/detail?name=CalendarPicker-source-1.0.0.zip&can=2&q=)

Thanks....!

Answer (score 1):

create one layout like this.... like **calender.xml**

Then inflate this in dialog box

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
RelativeLayout featureLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(ClassName.this, R.layout.popoverview, null);
dialog.setContentView(featureLayout);
```

dialog.show();