# Android Push Notification with client-only

Tags: android, calendar, push-notification, push

I'm trying to build an android app without using a server (i.e. hard coding logic in the client and uses database in the client to save and manipulate user inputs). Is it still possible to send push notifications and leverage native android calender app without using a server or cloud? Android SDK and SQLite would be mainly used, is there a possibility to code the logic and send notifications based on event triggers and syncing the time line with the native calendar?

The simpler solution would be really appreciated as there is not a lot of programming experience over here..

Thank you very much,

Cecilia

Comment: "to send push notifications" from where? and where will be stored application's user(device's ids or something that can identify user/devcice with your app)

Comment: The apps would be loaded on each device by bundling it from the emulator then downloaded on device, therefore the client does not need to be identified as it would be a local app on each device. The data would be stored in the database in the client as well. Does this not sound feasible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it still possible to send push notifications and leverage native android calender app without using a server or cloud?

No, because there is nothing to "send push notifications" if you do not have "a server or cloud", by definition.

If by "push notifications" you do not mean "push notifications", but rather "doing work on a scheduled basis", use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on AlarmManager, I will look into that. And to the other point, it was my bad to use the term "push notification". What i meant was essentially a function that allows the app to send notifications in terms of reminders, pop ups or feedback to user based on user input and/or time with respect to events (e.g. a reminder to go to the doctor's appointment)

Comment: @Cecilia: Yes, that sounds like `AlarmManager`. "Push notifications", as a term, is pretty much limited to things like GCM (Android), APN (iOS), and similar sorts of of cloud-to-device messaging.

Comment: Possibly use a log table in the database to record the notifications and use timestamp to check for time in device clock. The scenarios for event triggered notifications could be built by using conditions that retrieves information from the database when user makes new inputs. Does this sound feasible with Java and SQLite? Thanks again.

Comment: @Cecilia: That should be feasible, to the extent that I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand, but my english is not very good

You know there are systems such as PhoneGap or more of these systems by the server before my yapdığım had a method concentrated my WebView page is loaded from the html codes reading and methods, control and so on. I do not know I knew I 'il uses transactions.

which uses web services in a different way than you know, be able to record these transactions ta sqlite

there's a topic relevant to la datetimepicker

[How to create a datepicker like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460530/how-to-create-a-datepicker-like-this#comment15004572_10460530)

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately PhoneGap won't work in this case as there is limited time and knowledge on development so building a web browser then converting via PhoneGap and building a database then deploying in the emulator would have too many hand -overs between technology. But thank you very much for your help though!